# Is it correct to say "I've been to the World Trade Center"?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I've heard that you can't use the present perfect to talk about something which is not possible anymore. In this case, since the World Trade Center no longer exists and you can't visit there anymore, the sentence should be "I went to the World Trade Center." That's what I heard. Is that correct?

Comment: There's no "rule".

Comment: Can you remember where you heard or read this?

Comment: There's certainly a "rule of thumb" that we use present perfect to describe an event that occurred in the past *and is continuing into the present*, which is probably why at least *some* of us might find OP's example here slightly "odd". It's perhaps worth noting Hamlet's *Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him, Horatio, a fellow of infinite jest, of most excellent fancy. **He hath borne me** on his back a thousand times* - where arguably that Perfect form lends "immediacy / relevance to time of utterance" to his words.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *I've been to the World Trade Center **at least once in the past 30 years**.* It's still fine without that qualification. In fact, it's very much the syntax used on certain types of true or false game shows.

Comment: *since the World Trade Center no longer exists* the sentence should be either: 1."I went to the World Trade Center before 2001/it was destroyed." or 2. "I went/have been to **the site of** World Trade Center."

Answer (score -1):

"I've", which is the abbreviation of "I have", is correct.

Comment: Please can you provide the reason behind your answer? What makes it correct?